# android actionbar background color is grey instead of white

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

Is there any great solution that I could fix the problem ? I use @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light. My actionbar in Android 5 shows correct white. However, it's grey in Android 4. Do you guys have any idea? I search other solutions but none of them work. Please help me if you guys have any thought.

Comment: What is 'correct' changed from version to version of Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a custom style, and color it white. Check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) for more info